# Can I return custom object from UPDATE query instead of integer?

Tags: java, sql, spring-data

Executing UPDATE query it always returns INT number of rows affected.
Maybe there is some way to return for example list of all objects which where updated or first one updated?

I have @Entity SecurityPolicy and want this object back after update.
So here is my code:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "UPDATE security_policy s set max_fail_sign_in =:maxFailSignIn," +
        " min_password_length =:minPasswordLength," +
        " capital_in_password =:capitalInPassword," +
        " digit_in_password =:digitInPassword," +
        nativeQuery = true)
SecurityPolicy updateSecurityPolicy(@Param("maxFailSignIn") Integer maxFailSignIn,
                                          @Param("minPasswordLength") Integer minPasswordLength,
                                          @Param("capitalInPassword") Boolean capitalInPassword,
                                          @Param("digitInPassword") Boolean digitInPassword);
```

When using @Modifying it tells me that result should be Int, and without it - could not extract ResultSet.
I know with spring data you can easily save or update some entity and get it as a result, so I want achieve something similar.

Comment: Why do you have to use native query anyway? Cant you just use JPA and update SecurityPolicy entity?

Comment: Because this table doesn't have id field and within it is always only one row.

Comment: That should not be a problem. ID does not have to be a number. Anyway, with your approach - you cannot do that. But since clear and normal code is not your goal, you can just fetch that rown after update.

Comment: Yes, I know id can be anything but should be unique, and im my table there are no unique fields.

Comment: *have @Entity SecurityPolicy and want this object back after update.* Then use it to do the update...... You are making your life harder.

Comment: But you say its a single row..... ID in JPA is NOT PK. It just usually is but does not have to be.

Comment: Yes, in this table there is only single row, and all it's fields can be modified.

Comment: Like in answer - it cannot be done. Fetch entity after update.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot as the integer response is not generated by framework but by RDBMS itself (SQL spec). That integer says how many rows were modified by query.

Since you don't want to use JPA to do this, you will have to `SELECT` that row after update, like you would do with plain SQL.